# Showing Categories for Page Edit - without plugin

Tags: categories, pages, wp-editor

I am building a theme without any extra plugins. Does anyone know the code needed to show the Categories in page Edit - without using a plugin?

Answer (score 2):

What a great question. Here is the function:

```
function add_taxonomies_to_pages() {
      register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'page' );
      register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'page' );
  } 

 add_action( 'init', 'add_taxonomies_to_pages' );
```

Get back to winning, now.